# R: Replace Values by Row

Tags: r

I've got a Data Frame which looks like this:

```
ID1     | ID2 
I105    | I105
I122    | I122
**I107  | I108**
I118    | I118
**I139  | I140**
```

Now I would like to replace the "I108" in [3,2] with "I107" from [3,1]

Same with the values in row 5.

The actual list is a bit longer so I have to find a way to do that automatically.

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking to replace `ID1` values only if `ID1` and `ID2` differ.

```
transform(df, ID1 = ifelse(ID1 != ID2, ID2, ID1))

#   ID1  ID2
#1 I105 I105
#2 I122 I122
#3 I108 I108
#4 I118 I118
#5 I140 I140
```

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for. But it seems that ur code isn't working right.
When I run the code the first column transforms to this: c(1, 4, 2, 3, 5)

Comment: @Proki Do you have data as factors or lists? Run `df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)` and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much! But may I ask another question related to that:
How do I transform the code in the case a row in ID1 is na.
Then it should just loop over this row

Comment: You can use `is.na` to check for `NA` values. Something like this : `transform(df, ID1 = ifelse(ID1 != ID2 | is.na(ID1), ID2, ID1))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use an index to replace the values of 'ID2' with the corresponding values from 'ID1'

```
i1 <- c(3, 5)
df1 <- type.convert(df1, as.is = TRUE) # // in case if there are factor columns
# or if it is based on difference
i1 <- with(df1, ID2 != ID1)
df1$ID2[i1] <- df1$ID1[i1]
```

-output

```
df1
#.  ID1  ID2
#1 I105 I105
#2 I122 I122
#3 I108 I108
#4 I118 I118
#5 I140 I140
```

---

If we wanted to create a copy of ID1, just do the assignment.  No need of any conditions

```
df1$ID2 <- df1$ID1
```